# How to access or add template reference variable from angular within jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

How do I access a template reference/variable within Jasmine?

form.component.html

```html
<form #f="ngForm" class="form form-profession" novalidate>...

<div class="error-group" *ngIf="f.invalid">error</div>
```

form.component.ts

```js
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('f') f: NgForm;

  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit(f) {
    if (f.valid) {
      // do stuff
    }
  }
}
```

form.component.spec.ts

```js
it('should display errors when form is invalid', () => {
  fixture.componentInstance.f.invalid = true;
  expect(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.error-group')).not.toBeNull();
});
```

I get this error 
"[ts] Cannot assign to 'valid' because it is a constant or a read-only property."

Comment: Can you add the component code?

Comment: I have added it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this.

```
 it('should show error message when form is invalid', () => {
    const form = fixture.componentInstance.f;  // get the form instance through the component.
    form.form.setErrors({required: true}); // making the form invalid

    fixture.detectChanges(); // trigger a change detection cycle for the component

    expect(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.error-group').textContent).toContain('sss');

    expect(form.valid).toBeFalsy();
  });
```

Comment: I editted my post. What if I need to change the variable inside the component not outside.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand that.

Comment: Can you check again I have added more code. So what I want to do is check if the  div with errors do show up if the form is invalid.

Comment: what is the error that you are getting? `Property does not exist on type FormComponent`  which property ?

Comment: I've update the answer. Now it should work without any erros.

Comment: Thanks man your code works. But why if I set form.form.setErrors({required: false}); the form is still invalid

Comment: You should do `form.form.setErrors(null)`. Refer [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for the access to components `fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(ClassOfTheSearchedComponent))`