# unit test for template reference variable in angular

Tags: angular, jestjs, karma-jasmine

I have this code in html, which is used to disable a dropdown on ngAfterViewInit():

```
<select-field
        #dueBy
        width="100%"
        label=" "
        formControlName="dueByIndex"
        [options]="dueByValues"
        [ngClass]="{ disableUnEditableFields: showChanges }"
      ></select-field>
```

select-field is a customized tag provided by the customer.
In component class:

```
@ViewChild('dueBy') dueBySelect;
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.showChanges) {
      this.dueBySelect.control.disable();
}
```

I am trying to write the unit test for this but dueBySelect is coming as undefined. I have looked around but for the most cases the template reference variable is a target for some method calls. One try is as below:

```
it('should disable the advanced fields', () => {
    component.showChanges = true; // to go inside the if condition in ts file
    const dueBySelectInput: HTMLInputElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#dueBy');
    console.log(component.dueBySelect); // coming as undefined
```

Suggestions please!! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you modify something in your component during testing (like you did when setting `showChanges` to true), you need to trigger change detection on your fixture:

```js
it('should disable the advanced fields', () => {
    component.showChanges = true;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const dueBySelectInput: HTMLInputElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#dueBy');
    console.log(component.dueBySelect);
```

Comment: I did this, but fixture.detectChanges() throws an error for me. console.error
    Unhandled Promise rejection: No value accessor for form control with name: 
But even without doing fixture.detectChanges(), while debug, I see that the control is passing through component.showChanges and still this.dueBySelect is coming as undefined.

Comment: You need to run fixture.detectChanges, because otherwise the template won't be updated. The fact that it throws an error means you don't have all of the dependencies you need for this test. Is the component for <select-field> in your TestingModule?

Comment: Thanks Will. I added the component for <select-field> ,and the old error is gone. Currently, I am getting an error: Unhandled Promise rejection: Unhandled Promise rejection: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute. I am looking around without much luck, If you have any suggestions please let me know. thanks..

Comment: You need to provide the component to NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR : {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => SelectFieldComponentThingHere),
      multi: true
    }

Comment: I have added the above like this:
TestBed.configureTestingModule({//imports, etc}).overrideComponent(Component, { set : { providers: [{provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: forwardRef(() => SelectFieldComponentThingHere), multi: true }
Is this the way to do?

Comment: Hey Will, the issue that we were discussing in the chat is fixed. I tried the code in the answer provided by you, but dueBySelectInput is coming as null, and component.dueBySelect is coming as undefined. Any help please.

Comment: I was just thinking about this. If you are testing what another component is/can do inside the component you're testing, you're not writing a unit test: you're writing an integration test. Is that your aim here?

Comment: well, its not the other component. In the html , I am defining a template reference variable, and accessing it in component to disable that field.

Comment: I can't believe I only just noticed this. You're querying an element with `id="dueBy", which your element doesn't have. As for "disabling that field", what are you trying to check exactly? Does the test depend on the existence of the child component? If so, it's not a unit test.

Comment: yes right, I am testing on the existence of the child component. and by "disabling that field", I mean this line- this.dueBySelect.control.disable();

Comment: You're testing a child inside the parent, without actually testing the parent. It's not really a worthwhile test. Also, did you see what I said about the `id`? You're trying to query an element that doesn't exist in your template. `querySelector('#dueBy')` doesn't select an element with a local reference, it selects an element with an `id` of `dueBy`.

Comment: yes, I understood the point about id. I found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51150930/how-to-access-or-add-template-reference-variable-from-angular-within-jasmine) and trying like this:
component.dueBySelect = fixture.componentInstance.dueBySelect.nativeElement; Although this populates the dueBySelect, but is undefined when .control is called on it. So, do you think this is in right direction?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242117/discussion-between-will-alexander-and-abhinash-jha).

Answer (score 0):

As Will suggested, I changed the implementation for disabling the component.Below is the code from component:

```
this.taskForm.addControl('dueByIndex', this.dueByIndexControl);
this.dueByIndexControl.disable();
```

So, I don't need @ViewChild anymore. But in case someone faces it for some scenario, we can try the below:

```
component.dueBySelect = createMock(FormControl);
component.dueBySelect.disable = jest.fn(()=>true);
```